# Can't seem to rid of the extra 1px white border in my CSS menu

Tags: html, css

I can't seem, for the life of me, be able to find out so as to why, once the tab has been hovered over that this pesky 1px bottom line seems to appear. For this example, I have used MS paint to color it red for identification purposes. Is there anyway to fix or remove it?

The rendering browser is MS Edge.

Here's a pic of the problem:
[image]

```css
 h1 {
   padding: 100px 0;
   font-weight: 400;
   text-align: center;
 }

 p {
   margin: 0 0 20px;
   line-height: 1.5;
 }

 .main {
   margin: 0 auto;
   min-width: 320px;
   max-width: 800px;
 }

 .content {
   background: #fff;
   border: 1px solid rgb(97, 97, 97);
 }

 .content>div {
   display: none;
   padding: 20px 25px 5px;
 }

 input {
   display: none;
 }

 label {
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 15px 25px;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align: center;
   color: rgb(97, 97, 97);
 }

 label:hover {
   color: #000;
   cursor: pointer;
 }

 input:checked+label {
   background: #ccc;
   color: #000;
   border-top: 1px solid rgb(97, 97, 97);
   border-left: 1px solid rgb(97, 97, 97);
   border-right: 1px solid rgb(97, 97, 97);
   position: relative;
 }

 input:checked+label::before {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 1px;
   background: #ccc;
   bottom: -1px;
   right: 0;
   left: 0;
   margin: auto;
   content: '';
 }

 #tab1:checked~.content #content1,
 #tab2:checked~.content #content2,
 #tab3:checked~.content #content3,
 #tab4:checked~.content #content4 {
   display: block;
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
   label {
     padding: 15x 10px;
   }
 }
```

```html
 <div class="main">

   <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
   <label for="tab1">Workspace Info</label>

   <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
   <label for="tab2">Employee Info</label>

   <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
   <label for="tab3">Service Requests</label>

   <div class="content">
     <div id="content1">
       <p>
         New York – referred to as New York City or the City of New York to distinguish it from the State of New York, of which it is a part – is the most populous city in the United States and the center of the New York metropolitan area, the premier gateway
         for legal immigration to the United States and one of the most populous urban agglomerations in the world. A global power city, New York exerts a significant impact upon commerce, finance, media, art, fashion, research, technology, education,
         and entertainment.
       </p>
       <p>
         Home to the headquarters of the United Nations, New York is an important center for international diplomacy and has been described as the cultural and financial capital of the world.
       </p>
     </div>

     <div id="content2">
       <p>
         London is the capital city of England and the United Kingdom. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants. Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia,
         its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.
       </p>
       <p>
         London's ancient core, the City of London, largely retains its 1.12-square-mile (2.9 km2) mediaeval boundaries and in 2011 had a resident population of 7,375, making it the smallest city in England. Since at least the 19th century, the term London has
         also referred to the metropolis developed around this core.
       </p>
     </div>

     <div id="content3">
       <p>
         Mumbai is the capital city of the Indian state of Maharashtra. It is the most populous city in India, most populous metropolitan area in India, and the eighth most populous city in the world, with an estimated city population of 18.4 million and metropolitan
         area population of 20.7 million as of 2011. Along with the urban areas, including the cities of Navi Mumbai, Thane, Bhiwandi, Kalyan, it is one of the most populous urban regions in the world.
       </p>
       <p>
         Mumbai lies on the west coast of India and has a deep natural harbour. In 2009, Mumbai was named an alpha world city. It is also the wealthiest city in India, and has the highest GDP of any city in South, West or Central Asia.
       </p>
     </div>

   </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: Please provide a simple and reproductible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: input checked before has bottom -1px

Comment: Your code seems fine. I tried it on Chrome and Edge with no isses.

Comment: Madhuchhanda still no difference if removed.

Comment: I can add a body bg color and don't see the space your image shows and looks fine. Is this in a specific browser or something?

Answer (score 0):

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(97, 97, 97);
    background: rgb(222,222,222); <-- Add this to your foreground background color
}
```

Comment: Please describe in your answer, what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine in Mozilla, chrome, and edge. But I suggest adding text-decoration: none property to label: hover.
The CSS looks like this,

```
label:hover,
label:active,
label:focus{color: #000;cursor: pointer;text-decoration:none;}
```

Thank you.